# List all executables in the cwd with grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to list all the executable files in the cwd using grep, and I used the following:

```
ls -F -a | grep "[*]$"
```

And it works, but why doesn't the following command work? It should be equivalent:

```
ls -F -a | grep -E "[*]\>"
```

Oddly enough, if I use a standard character as ending letter (like grep -E "[a]>") it works just fine

Comment: Just edit your question

Comment: `ls -a | grep "[*]$"` works?? are you sure? you have `alias ls=...` right? also your question is not clear, `executable` for whom? owner? user? group??

Comment: Sorry I forgot the -F flag :)

Comment: Just any exectuable is fine

Comment: And why '[*]\>' doesn't work?

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks! You should add your comment as an answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls -F | grep -E "[*]\>"
```

This won't do what you are expecting because `*` is not a "word" character and looking for an end-of-word boundary immediately after it makes no sense.

```
ls -F -a | grep "[*]$"
```

Will yield all lines ending with `*` as specified. This makes sense.

You should heed [@Adam's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14687017/78845): You should not parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: In Zsh, I would just do `echo *(*)` :)

Comment: Thank you :) Adam's advice is certainly a much better option than parsing "ls", but it doens't answer my question. Your answer is exactly what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the find utility, this is more robust than parsing the output of ls.

For example list files in the current directory with execute bit set for user.

```
find . -maxdepth 1  -type f -perm -u=x
```

Comment: `find . -type f -perm -u=x -depth 1` to find regular executable files in the current directory (and no deeper).

Comment: Hmm it works, but I have to use ls and grep. My question is, why doesn't special characters like "* . \" work before a "\>" in a regular expression?

Comment: @Johnsyweb Thanks, updated answer, couldn't quite get your example with -depth 1 working though, used maxdepth instead.

Comment: Ah. Different flavours of `find`!

Comment: @user1417683: "but I have to use ls and grep" ***Why?***

Comment: @Johnsyweb Because this is a question asked in an university exam. It clearly states to do it with grep and ls. Of course, normally I would use find :)

Comment: I find the questions asked by educational institutions increasingly odd.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Hahah, I totally agree. It looks like our teacher doesn't know about find